# Guidelines for JavaFX Property Usage

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

Before asking, this topic can be argumentative, and the response requested here are just guideline points rather than definitive or hard and fast rule answers.  Having said that, I hope that if insightful responses are given, it could be a worthwhile to keep this thread, even if it is closed after sufficient and good information is posted.

The question:  With the advent of JavaFX property, and that it is possible to use it beyond JavaFX applications, what points are to be consider when incorporating JavaFX property in data objects?

Consider the following example:

```
class BasicPersonBean
{
    private String name;
    private PropertyChangeSupport propChgSup;

    BasicPersonBean(String name)
    {
        this.propChgSup = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

        this.name = name;
    }

    BasicPersonBean() { this(null); }

    public String getName() { return this.name; }

    public void setName(String newValue)
    {
        String oldValue = this.getName();
        this.name = newValue;
        this.propChgSup("name", oldValue, newValue);
    }
}
```

```
class PersonBeanUsingJavaFXProperty
{
    private StringProperty name;
    private PropertyChangeSupport propChgSup;

    BasicPersonBean(String name)
    {
        this.propChgSup = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    }

    BasicPersonBean() { this(null); }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() { return this.name; }

    public String getName() { return this.name.get(); }

    public void setName(String newValue)
    {
        String oldValue = this.getName();
        this.name.set(newValue);
        this.propChgSup("name", oldValue, newValue);
    }
}
```

Both classes serve very similar functionality.  The latter one, PersonBeanWithJavaFXProperty, is more 'end user application ready', such as JavaFX application.  Though JavaFX do have adapter classes to help wire up the former class, BasicPersonBean.

The ability to have bidirectional bound properties ready to hook up as it is in the latter class is very handy, let alone time saving.

However, there is always trade off.  As JavaFX property is relatively new, and less documented (compared to well established/matured standards/library/conventions) what are these trade offs?

Stating the obvious trade off, as a negative for using JavaFX Property, is processing and memory footprint.  However, there are ways to offset to that via setting up these properties using half/full lazy loading.

Another is testing complexity with JavaFX property, could some explanation or cautionary notes be advise regarding this aspect?  In JavaFX property tutorial, memory footprint and processing is discussed, but testing aspect was not mentioned.

In summary, could a list of pros and cons be compile here to help programmers in deciding 
when to use 'non-JavaFX property' and 'JavaFX property'?

Again, stressing that this is just educational and/or information thread, and there is not or should not be one definitive answer.  Just points to consider and making informed choices.

Lastly, the 'JavaFX Property' tag was intended to be added, however, it does not exist and could not be created due to (my) insufficient reputation.  If the 'JavaFX Property' tag can be added by someone else, please do, as it is a more relevant and concise tag than just 'javafx'.